# Add Navigation in Smart Table

Tags: sapui5

I'm working on UI and I have problems with adding navigation in smart table.
I already bind the data to the smart table. Now the smart table can show all my data. Then I want to make every item (every row) a link that navigate to another view, which is the detail of this item. But the smart table is not like the normal table, it doesn't a property that allows me to change the item type to be navigation.
My smarttable codes are like this:

So how can I achieve navigation in smart table?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The SmartTable allows you to add your own table definition. Of course you can use a ColumnListItem with type Navigation for the items aggregation. An [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable.mtableCustom/code) with an own table definition can be found in the UI5 Explored application.

Comment: Hi matbtt, would that require the definition of a new datafield? I just i want to use what is given by the odatamodel, without having to define a new field. With annotations I've decided what should be visible. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Ah okay, i can just add the template without any data in it, thus having the option to define the type and press of the columnListItem. Thanks!